# Prism MVVM ValidatableBindableBase doesn't exist in Prism.StoreApps

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, prism

I'm learning to use Prism MVVM for Windows Store Apps. I have encountered a problem with ValidateBindableBase which is supposed to exist in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps. But it doesn't exist there or in any of the other libraries that you get when installing with nuget.

From what I have seen in documentation the class exists in version 1.1.0.0 of the library but is missing along with many others from version 2.0.0.0 (which is what nuget installed).

Does anybody know why these classes are missing in the later version or where I can find them?

P.S: Rolling back versions is a solution that I don't want to follow at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/discussions/563181

Apparently this answers my question. It is not available for winrt.